# Multiple word search

Tags: c, arrays, string, search

I wish to come up with a code that will allow me to return the position of a key word multiple times. For example, the program below returns 9, the position inside of the array that is the the occurrence of the first Point. However, I wish to search for all key words within an entire array, since key words can appear multiple times in the arrays I am tasked to search. Basically I want to be able to return 9, 17 and so on and so on depending on the string.

I was thinking of putting into a loop of some sort but I am not experienced with the strstr command to know for sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char haystack[30] = "TutorialsPointandPoint";
   char needle[10] = "Point";
   char *ret;

   ret = strstr(haystack, needle);
   printf("The substring is: %d\n", ret-haystack);

   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As strstr returns the pointer to first occurence of your search string you can use the return value as new startpoint for your strstr, as long as you do not get a null pointer.

More or less:

```
ret = strstr(haystack, needle);
while(ret!=NULL)
{
printf("The substring is: %t\n", ret-haystack);
ret++;
ret = strstr(ret , needle); 
}
```

Comment: +1, but `null` is usually spelled `NULL`, and some compilers (rightly so) complain about using `%d` for a `size_t` pointer subtraction.

Comment: yes you are right, the better solution would be to use the %zp for the printf.

Comment: Actually, the type that results from the difference of two pointers is a signed type, `ptrdiff_t` (rather than an unsigned type like `size_t`), and the correct format length qualifier is `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Tobias is on the right track, but remember that `strstr` will match the needle at the beginning of the string, so you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
int main() {
    char haystack[] = "TutorialsPointandPoint";
    char needle[] = "Point";

    char *search = haystack;

    while(search != NULL)
    {
        search = strstr(search, needle);

        if(search)
        {
            search++;
            printf("The substring is: %zu\n", search - haystack);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  int a=0;
  ret = strstr(haystack+a,needle);
  printf("The substring is: %d\n", (a=ret-haystack));
    while(strlen(haystack+a+strlen(needle))>strlen(needle))
    {
       ret = strstr(haystack+a+strlen(needle),needle);
       printf("The substring is: %d\n", (a=ret-haystack));
    }
```